# Why use "OMIT" components on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, resistors

I have some experience with highfrequency circuit analysys. However I am a newbie in PCB design. I am analysing this circuit:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu365b/spmu365b.pdf (starts on page 36)
and regularly see things like "OMIT" for headerpins or components like resistors or so.

e.g.:

- p41 (6/6): the boxheader(?) on the left.
- P40 (5/6): R48 on the dev board are two small surfaces with some soldering on it but no component apparently. I can hardly see myself (de)soldering resistors on my new dev board...

Why is this being mentionned? What do the people who made the PCB mean by this?

I mean if this part has to be omitted, why did they even place it on the PCB?

Thx

Comment: similar question  :  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138378/why-does-there-seem-to-be-a-missing-component-in-many-pcbs?rq=1

Comment: You might hardly see yourself desoldering resistors on dev kits, I do it frequently when trying to evaluate different options for a component.

Comment: Also very similar to: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/112258/25328

Answer (score 7):

Extra/omitted parts on a PCB can be very useful for

a) Having multiple versions of a circuit able to be built with only one PCB

b) Debugging, when I lay out an RF board I often put an omitted 1k SMD resistor from the line finishing near to a ground pad. Invaluable to solder a 50ohm coax to for probing the signal on the line, with good RF integrity and without damaging the line. A JTAG or RJ45 socket may be handy for digital access to a board for debug, but is not needed in production, it's omitted for cost or because it won't fit in the final production case.

c) You may often see a 0 ohm resistor in series with a power line, for monitoring current, or isolating parts of the circuit. These pads may also have a trace under them to short them in the normal case, the trace can be cut to use the component.

Comment: Also sometimes I see omitted 0 ohm resistors that get hand soldered into the device in a multistage signal path, where each stage is tested seperately, and only then all are connected together

Comment: Other terms which mean the same thing are "Do not load" (DNL) or "Do not populate" (DNP).

Comment: Also "DNI" for do not install, or simply "NOLOAD".

Comment: I have also seen "DNS" for "Do Not Stuff", but I'm not sure how common this one is.