# What does "NS" indicate as a capacitor value?

Tags: capacitor, diagram

I'm looking at [an application note](https://www.monolithicpower.com/DesktopModules/DocumentManage/API/Document/GetDocument?id=3471#page=2), and it contains the following in the circuit diagram:

[image]

What does the  `NS` in the diagram represent? Or is this just a typo on the behalf of the manufacturer?

---

**Edit:** Further down the datasheet, this is clarified as "Not stuffed"

[image]

What does *that* mean?

Comment: I would say it means something like "Not soldered" or similar. Meaning it is not populated in this assembly.

Comment: Not Stuffed. It is in the data sheet in the BOM section. Not Stuffed means that it is not on the Board.

Comment: @Tyler: yep, you just beat me to it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NS means "No stuff".  This is an assembly instruction.  Nothing will be placed on the PCB for C7.

NS is yet another abbreviation along with DNL (do not load), DNP (do not populate), DNI (do not install), DNS (do not stuff), NOLOAD, OMIT.

#### Related threads

[Why use "OMIT" components on a PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245467/why-use-omit-components-on-a-pcb)
['Not Mount' on PCB Design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112258/not-mount-on-pcb-design)
[Why does there seem to be a missing component in many PCBs?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138378/why-does-there-seem-to-be-a-missing-component-in-many-pcbs)

Comment: "No solder" as well?