# Meaning of NS in this circuit

Tags: circuit-design, push-pull

I have the following Circuit from a datasheet, the three ports are suppose to be set to create programmable address values in a PCA9548A chip.

I see they both have pull up and pull down, but its labeled NS on one of the two sides. Is that trying to tell me that one labeled is not on? I am just trying to figure out what the address values are set as so that I can address it

[image]

Comment: This might be of interest https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246628/what-does-ns-indicate-as-a-capacitor-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NS in this case means "no-stuff" i.e. the pads for that component exist on the PCB, but that component is not installed. This means that A0 is high (pulled up), and A1 and A2 are low (pulled down).